# jquery autocomplete for textbox: different value and text

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

So, this question has come up a few times, generally with 'input's and most are in MVC3. I'm hoping things have changed. I'm using jquery and autocomplete, and want to save  'value' instead of the 'label'. However, the users need to see the meaningful label, not the random numbers in a primary key users don't care about.

Maybe its because I started in webforms, but i'm amazed that MVC controls seem to have completely lost the concept of separating value from text. Amazed enough to think the problem is probably I'm missing something,

So how do I save the value and display the label of a selected item in this textbox without needing the hidden field and model property? In this instance ContactName is the important value to save.

**Razor**

```
     @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Issue.ContactNameDisplay, new { style = "width: 100%", id = "ContactNameDisplay" })
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Issue.ContactName, new {id = "ContactName"})
```

**Autocomplete**:

```
$('#ContactNameDisplay').autocomplete(
       {
           dataType: 'json',
           source: function (request, response) {
               $.get('@Url.Action("LoadAdFullNames", "Order")', { phrase: request.term }, function (data) {
                   response($.map(data, function (item) {
                       return {
                           label: item.Text,
                           value: item.Value,
                       };
                   }));
               });
           },
           select: function (event, ui) {
               event.preventDefault();
               $('#ContactName').val(ui.item.val);
               $(this).val(ui.item.val);
              $(this).text(ui.item.label);       //Breaks Here
               $.get('@Url.Action("LoadPhoneNumber", "Order")', { windowsId: ui.item.value }, function (data) {
                   $('#ContactPhone').val(data.toString());
               });

           },
           focus: function (event, ui) {
               event.preventDefault();
               $(this).text(ui.item.label);
           },
       });
```

Comment: An important thing to remember when coming from Web Forms to MVC is that in MVC there are no controls, there are helpers.  Helpers are simply convenience methods for rendering HTML.  The only thing that was "lost" in MVC was the monolithic viewstate that made it seem like all the data was there.  It all renders as HTML in the end and if it's web forms you get a giant nasty hidden input with the encrypted viewstate.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean to lament webforms in general, just seemed like i was going through a lot of hoops.

Comment: I think initially MVC does give that impression of "Where did everything go?" because it is returning to the true stateless nature of the web and the paradigm of the client server model where you don't always have the information available and hanging around like you do in a desktop application, which is what Web Forms was mean to emulate but on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Input element does not have the text property.**

```
$(this).val(ui.item.label);  // Show the value in the textbox
```

Store the info in a **HTML-5 data-* attributes**

```
    $(this).data('key', ui.item.val);
```

To retrieve the key you can just use

```
$(this).data('key')
```

Comment: TextBox renders as `<input type="text"` in the `DOM`

Comment: TextBoxFor is an html helper that returns an input.

Comment: You're right, I rechecked. I got it in my head that was what editorFor was for.

Comment: To retrieve the data on form submit, any recommendations on where to place that? Or would i be better off changing to a textArea to make 'look' like a TextBox?

Comment: That value will never be seen by the user. So on submit you can just access that field in the submit event and pass it to DB.. `$('id or class').data('key')` should get you that specific value

Comment: Good news- It worked: Bad news, its more of a hassle to use because I need that html-5 data- data attribute pre-populated with the original data. It answered my question, but I'm gonna use the hidden field.